# Memory management, should I be retaining?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

If I declare an NSString in my header file as follows:

```
{
  NSString *testString; 
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *testString;
```

Then synthesize the string in my .m file, what is the correct way to initialise it?
If I don't write:
     `self.testString = [[NSString alloc] init];`

then the it is never initialised, but if I do, then isn't the string being retained twice? Or should I initialise it some other way, such as:

`self.testString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, sampleText];`

Comment: no need to alloc it here. just assigning it a string value such as you did with [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, sampleText]; is fine. because u use the retain property everytime you assign to self.testString it will handle any releases/retains for you. may need to self.testString = nil or release in dealloc still though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the former will over retain the object.

Use the second form instead.
If you had to use the *ivar* directly however, you need to retain the object :

```
testString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, sampleText] retain];
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be doing the same thing though? Over-retaining the string?

Comment: No, since I think Vince referred to simple class variable, not a property.

Comment: no, in this case you are assigning value to ivar, not to property, so this code is correct.

Comment: not if you use the ivar (testString) instead of the property (self.testString). Of course if the reference is already initialized, you need to release the previous object

Answer (score 1):

`self.testString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, sampleText];` or `self.testString = [NSString string];` is correct; `self.testString = [[NSString alloc] init];` will cause over-retaining.

Consider using ARC (Automatic Retain Counting) for you project. With ARC the compiler takes care of retain counts so you don't have to, in fact aren't allowed to. There is a refactoring that will convert a current project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you declare an variable called testString in your .h and you also create a property that retains.

You can either use this:

```cpp
self.testString = [NSString string];
```

or you can use

```cpp
testString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

Defining the variable through the property will cause it to be retained, that's why you declared it as (nonatomic, retain). Defining the variable through the declaration won't take those arguments into consideration. Here's a quick rule of thumb about retaining.

Using your code as a base:

```cpp
self.testString = [[NSString alloc] init]; // Retain count = 2
self.testString = [NSString string];       // Retain count = 1
testString = [[NSString alloc] init];      // Retain count = 1
testString = [NSString string];            // Not retained at all.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *testString` to avoid mutability bugs.
Second - if you want just a string without leaks:

```
self.testString = [NSString string];
self.testString = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
self.testString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", text];
```

these are all valid options.